# Inverse laplace 2/((s-1)^2+1)^2

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> Find inverse laplace transform of $$\frac{2}{((s-1)^2+1)^2}$$

I tried to decompose the fraction using

$$\because (s-1)^2+1=s^2-2s+2$$

$$\rightarrow \frac{2}{((s-1)^2+1)^2}=\frac{As+B}{s^2-2s+2}+\frac{Cs+D}{(s^2-2s+2)^2}$$

yet I get D=2, which leads me back to the same exact equation, any help?

(I have also tried the $\frac{-d}{ds}(L{\{sint\}})$ propertie, but failed since there's no variable s in the numerator)

Comment: $$e^t (\sin (t)-t \cos (t))$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is a defined inverse Laplace transform, the integral is often difficult.  Usually, it is easier to take the transforms we know and noodle with them until we find a fit.

$L\{e^t\cos t\} = \frac {s-1}{(s-1)^2+1}\\
L\{e^t\sin t\} = \frac 1{(s-1)^2+1} = \frac {s^2-2s +2}{((s-1)^2+1)^2}\\
L\{te^t\cos t\} = -\frac {d}{ds} \frac {(s-1)}{(s-1)^2+1} = \frac {s^2 - 2s}{((s-1)^2+1)^2}\\
L\{te^t\sin t\} = -\frac {d}{ds} \frac 1{(s-1)^2+1} = \frac {2s-2}{((s-1)^2+1)^2}$

Some combination of $(s^2 - 2s + 2), (s^2-2s),(2s-2) = 2$

$e^t \sin t - te^t \cos t$

Comment: That second statement is rather dubious given $$f(t)=\mathscr{L}\{F\}(t)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma- i \infty}^{\sigma+ i \infty}F(s)e^{st}\,ds$$gives the inverse Laplace Transform of $F(s)$.  And in this case there are two second order poles from which application of the residue theorem circumvents the "noodle with ..." effort.  Now, alongside this, there are straightforward and systematic approaches to handle simple problems, such as the one of record, that don't require direct valuation of the inversion integral.

Comment: I am aware of that integral, and I don't think it is particularly easy... but I will qualify my opening statement.

Comment: In this case, application of the inversion integral is easy - $F(s)$ has two second order poles.  So, application of the residue theorem is a snap.  The "noodle" comment is the dubious one.  There is a systematic approach for this kind of problem that relies on exploiting a couple of LT properties as given in the "HINT" i posted.

Comment: Noodle may be a bad choice of words, but it is how I think of it.  I could say $L\{t^n e^t \cos t\}, L\{t^{n+1} e^t \sin t\}$ forms a basis for the space of functions of the form $\frac {p_n(s)}{s^2 - 2s +2}$.  But, that is just not as much fun

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Use the following properties

$$\mathscr{L}\{tf(t)\}(s)=-\frac{d}{ds}\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}(s)$$

$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{s_0t}f(t)\}(s)=\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}(s-s_0)\,\,\,\,\,\,$$

along with these Laplace Transform pairs

$$\mathscr{L}\{\cos(t)\}(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+1}$$

$$\mathscr{L}\{\sin(t)\}(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+1}$$